# Efficient SQL to retrieve top results

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table:

```
id, first_name, last_name, score, feedback, report_date
1,  Barry     , Smith    , 5    , positive, 2017-02-01
2,  John      , Smith    , 6    , negative, 2017-02-01
3,  Barry     , Smith    , 3    , negative, 2017-01-31
5,  John      , Smith    , 1    , positive, 2017-01-31
```

I would like to retrieve the latest score and feedback for first and last name.

I tried the following query:

```
select m.ad_id, m.country, m.score, m.feedback
from records m
inner join  (
   select first_name, last_name, max(report_date) as max_date
   from records
   where report_date <= '2017-02-19 15:00:00'
     and report_date >='2017-02-19 10:00:00'
     and score is not null
   GROUP BY first_name, last_name
   ) mp  on m.first_name = mp.first_name
         and m.last_name=mp.last_name
         and m.report_date = mp.max_date
         and m.report_date <= '2017-02-19 15:00:00'
         and m.report_date>='2017-02-19 10:00:00'
   ;
```

However, on 18M records it takes a few seconds.

Making a simple query:

```
select m.fist_name, m.last_name, m.score, m.feedback
from records m
where m.report_date <= '2017-02-19 15:00:00'
  and m.report_date>='2017-02-19 10:00:00' 
  and score is not null
```

Taking less than half a second, however it would return x amount of records which takes more traffic.
How can I make the first query more efficient?

Comment: `last_name) mp` it looks like there is a part missing from the query.

Comment: You are right, I missed the first select. added it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`distinct on`

```
select distinct on (first_name, last_name) *
from records
where
    report_date <= '2017-02-19 15:00:00' and report_date >='2017-02-19 10:00:00' 
    and score is not null
order by first_name, last_name, report_date desc
```

Comment: is there something like this also in SQLite?